# Add method dynamically to class _without_ exposing method in python

Tags: python

I have a library that for various reasons I want to build up in pieces (mainly so I can document them, work on them and test them independently in a notebook).

Suppose I have an owner class `Parse` - and I want to add a bunch of static methods to it.

This code works:

```py
def _internal_parse_one_of( *list_of_possible_matches ):
    parsers = as_parsers( list_of_possible_matches )
    if len(parsers) == 0:
        raise Exception("no parsers were provided")
    the_whole_expression = None
    for parser in parsers:
        the_whole_expression = parser if the_whole_expression is None else the_whole_expression.or_else( parser )
    return the_whole_expression 

Parse.one_of = _internal_parse_one_of 

Parse.one_of( "x", "y", "z").test_pass("xavier", "x")
Parse.one_of( "x", "y", "z").test_pass("yellow", "y")
Parse.one_of( "x", "y", "z").test_pass("zebra", "z")
Parse.one_of( "x", "y", "z", Parse.any_char).test_pass("abracadabra", "a")
```

but it *leaks* this "_internal_parse_one_of" definition out into the global namespace. Is there any way of achieving the same goal without leaking anything?

Comment: Don't add it to your class if you don't want it part of it? Why not just leave them as module-level functions? And FYI, your setattr with a static string as the second argument does not make sense, it's the same as `Parse.one_of = ...`

Comment: you are correct - I got rid of setattr.

Comment: but I'm creating a library - I don't want to pollute the global namespace with a bunch of functions - I have _hundreds_ of these creation helper  functions - and I want them all to hang off Parse - I'll add tests as an example of how it gets used

Comment: How about deleting the references, once you set the helper functions as attributes?

Comment: that's not bad - how do I do that?

Comment: Python does not have a global namespace (the "global" scope is the module), and using an underscore prefix for internal functions is standard in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So my first somewhat crude answer would be to define the helper function, set it as an attribute of Parse and then delete the original reference.

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
        
def my_func():
    print('yay')
    
Test.my_method = my_func
del my_func


Test.my_method()

try:
    my_func()
except NameError:
    print('We don’t pollute on Stackoverflow')
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on @AlexNe's answer, here's a function that will add an arbitrary function to an arbitrary class's namespace, then delete the reference to that function in the global namespace. I made the name for the new method an optional argument; `assign_then_delete_from_globals` defaults to using the function's existing name if you don't assign it a new name.

```
def assign_then_delete_from_globals(func, cls, new_func_name=''):
    """Monkey-patch a function `func` onto a class `cls`,
    then delete the reference to `func` from the global namespace.

    If the user does not specify the name
    they wish the function to be assigned to,
    the function's existing name is used as a default."""

    old_func_name = func.__name__

    if new_func_name:
        func.__name__ = func.__qualname__ = new_func_name
    else:
        new_func_name = old_func_name

    setattr(cls, new_func_name, func)
    del globals()[old_func_name]


class Test:
    pass


def my_func():
    print('yay')


assign_then_delete_from_globals(my_func, Test, new_func_name='my_method')

Test.my_method()

try:
    my_func()
except NameError:
    print('We don’t pollute on Stackoverflow')
```